# Concurrent Ajax requests with Rxjs

Tags: ajax, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I'am currently switched from promises to observables. I am using Redux-Observable for my react app. Basically, I am looking for the best operator that will enable mutliple, concurrent ajax calls and return the responses when all the observables have sucessfully finished executing. 
Here is a code snippet from my app.

```
let epicPostAd = (action$, store, {ajax}) =>
  action$.ofType(POST_AD)
   .debounceTime(1000)
   .mergeMap(({ payload }) =>
     ajax(generateAjaxRequestSetting(POSTS_URL, 'post', payload,CT_JSON))
      .map(response => postAdSuccessful(response))
      .catch(e => Observable.of(postAdUnsuccessful(e.xhr.response)))
      .takeUntil(action$.ofType(LOCATION_CHANGE))
    )
```

It is a simple ajax request that posts given ad and dispatches `POST_AD_SUCCESSFUL` when response is 201 else dispatches `POST_AD_UNSUCCESSFUL` on error. 
But the issues is I want to make subsequent ajax observable stream when there is a response. Such as

```
.map(response => /* start a stream of ajax observables then process the response */)
```

I will appreciate if you show me the optimal way of achieving this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [`forkJoin` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

It will subscribe to all the Observables you pass to it and after they **all** complete, it will emit the last value from each inside an array.

It wasn't entirely clear where in your Epic you wanted to do this, so I just made a generic example:

```
const somethingEpic = (action$, store, { ajax }) =>
  action$.ofType(SOMETHING)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.forkJoin(
        ajax('/first'),
        ajax('/second'),
        ajax('/third')
      )
      .do(results => {
        // the results is an array, containing each
        const [first, second, third] = results;
        console.log(first, second, third);
      })
      .map(results => ({
        type: 'SOME_RESULTS',
        results
      }))
    );
```

Technically, it supports a final `resultSelector` argument you can use instead of using the `map` operator after it, but I tend not to use it because I've found it's less clear with only negligible performance benefits in common redux-observable style cases. But it's still good to know. Can be handy for more "data-normalization" stuff rather than "transform this into an action" stuff.

```
const somethingEpic = (action$, store, { ajax }) =>
  action$.ofType(SOMETHING)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.forkJoin(
        ajax('/first'),
        ajax('/second'),
        ajax('/third'),
        results => ({
          type: 'SOME_RESULTS',
          results
        })
      )
    );
```

---

ALSO, if you're asking yourself "what operator do I use?" you should try the operator wizard located in the documentation: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/

Scroll down to the part that says:

> **Do you need to find an operator for your problem? Start by choosing an option from the list below:**
>
> - I have one existing Observable, and...
> - I have some Observables to combine together as one Observable, and...
> - I have no Observables yet, and...
>
> **Hint: open your DevTools to experiment with RxJS.**

Though in this case, `forkJoin` is correctly suggested but when you click on it, it isn't yet documented :sadface: But a google search would present many different websites explaining what it does and how to use it (in RxJS and in other Rx implementations in other languages). Like [this helpful website](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Comment: That wizard is neat! It should be made more prominent; I've never noticed it before.

Comment: And I confirm it suits my case and works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my own question. Although JayPhelps answered, I realized that my question was not so clear. Using Jay's recommendation. I came up with the following:

```
let epicPostAd = (action$, store, {ajax, observable}) =>
  action$.ofType(POST_AD)
   .debounceTime(1000)
   .mergeMap(({ payload }) =>
     ajax(generateAjaxRequestSetting(POSTS_URL, 'post', payload, CT_JSON))
      .mergeMap(response =>
        observable.forkJoin(
          ajax(''),
          ajax('')
        )
      .do(res => {
        const [first, second, third] = results;
        console.log(first, second, third);
      })
      .map(res => postAdSuccessful(res))
    )
    .catch(e => observable.of(postAdUnsuccessful(e.xhr.response)))
    .takeUntil(action$.ofType(LOCATION_CHANGE))
```

)

So here how it works. I make a post request and immediately after ajax request finishes execution I `.mergeMap` the response to a stream of ajax ovservables using `.forkJoin()`. Then process the results

Comment: **Just in case** I want to point out that the `.do()` operator usage I added was totally optional as a debugging tool.